# ->first() return an empty array despite getting results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables I need to query.
Everything works fine so far, I get everything back I want, but as I just want to select the element in the array that holds the min price I want to `->first()` on that one:

```
return Product::with(['price' => function($query) use ($today) {
            $query->where(function ($subquery1) {
                $subquery1-> *applying some filter here*
            })->where(function ($timequery) use ($today){
                $timequery->where('startingDate', '<=', $today)->where('endingDate', null)
                    ->orWhere('startingDate', null)->where('endingDate', '<=', $today)
                    ->orWhere('startingDate', '<=', $today)->where('endingDate', '>=', $today)
                    ->orWhere('startingDate', null)->where('endingDate', null);

            })->orderBy('price', 'asc');
        }])->with('defaultPrice')->whereIn('id', $array)->get();
```

This works good so far. However, occassionally I get back 2 or more rows for the price relation (which is ok). However, I just want to select the first element in the array there.
When I put `->first()` straight after `->orderBy('price', 'asc')` I just get back an empty array.
When I put it before `with('defaulPrice')` I dont even get back my price relation
What am I actually missing here?

EDIT: Once I query for a single product with `where('id', 'someId')` it works, so this is down to `whereIn...` Anybody can explain me why and knows a way around this?

Comment: `->first()` after `orderBy()` will only limit the results of each `$product->price` to a single result, but `->get()` is still being called at the end of your main query, which returns a Collection. If you only want a single `Product`, then you need to replace `->get()` with `->first()`.

Comment: Sorry if this wasnt clear, but I want all Products I pass in, but said products can have multiple prices. and of that prices I only want the first one I get after orderBy

Comment: Oh I got ya. Then after `->orderBy('price', 'asc')`, add `->limit(1)`.

Comment: Sadly returns an empty array. This is what throws me off massivly. When I have nothing after orderBy I get back an array of price.
Once I add first() or limit(1) or take(1) the array is empty

Comment: Edited my question. whereIn messes it up

Comment: by the way, I see you pass $today in the closure, you can just call Carbon::today() right where you want to use it or assign $today = Carbon::today(); inside the closure.